# How to localize specific phrasing on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, nslocalizedstring

I have a few phrases on iPhone that translate in diverse logical blocks in some languages. 
For example, in English it will be:

```
You have 5 camels in the Paris store
```

where in French it will be

```
Vous avez 5 chameaux dans le magasin de Paris
```

I don't quite get how to solve this, given the number of elements, the type of element (camel in this exemple) and the place are variable. I chose camels in this example on purpose, because you can't simply add a "S" at the end to mark multiplicity as in English or with some other words. If it was bottles we were talking about:

```
Vous avez 5 bouteilles dans le magasin de Paris
```

Does anyone have an idea? I don't really think I should implement a grammatical system to decide whether to add X, S or whatever else is the mark of multiplicity in the language used...

I should make clear that the NSLocalizedString currently are used inside a NSStringWithFormat of the form `@"%@ %d %@ %@ %@"`, with the second and the last `%@` built on the fly from an appropriate language database, and the first as well as third `%@` gotten from the localization strings file. Also, to elaborate on @rckoenes's answer, what he suggested is already implemented, but as I explained it's not the problem I have an issue with :D

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is create to translations with string format in the `Localizable.strings` file.

The in code do something like:

```
NSString *camelStringFormat = nil;

if (numberOFCamels > 1) {
    camelStringFormat = NSLocalizedString(@"OnCamel", @"Translation for one camel");
} else {
    camelStringFormat = NSLocalizedString(@"MultipleCamels", @"Translation for multiple camels");
}

NSString *camelString = [NSString stringWithFormat:camelStringFormat, numberOFCamels, city];
```

Where `Localizable.strings` for englis  would look like:

```
"OnCamel" = "You have %d camel in the %@ store"
"MultipleCamels" = "You have %d camels in the %@ store"
```

Where `Localizable.strings` for france would look like:

```
"OnCamel" = "Vous avez %d chameau dans le magasin de %@"
"MultipleCamels" = "Vous avez %d chameaux dans le magasin de %@"
```

Comment: No, this doesn't work. It solves the standard issue of multiplicity, but as I explained in my example, it doesn't solve the language-specific forms like 1 chameau, 2 chameaux that occur once in a while. And it is quite ugly to have an app that rightly says 1 chien, 2 chiens, and wrongly says 1 chameau, 2 chameaus :D

Comment: You want to update your website, "formally" should be spelled "formerly" :D Goeiemiddag!

Comment: But then I need as many switch cases as there are rules per language. It will end up being its own little LEX/YACC analyser...

Comment: Can you give an example where 2, 3 or more would give other spelling of the animals name? Zo no just 1 chameau or 2 chameaux, 3 chameaux.

Comment: Actually, I made the example up to simplify a more complicated issue, like using adjectives (which I need to), and there are other rules (like nose, in French, doesn't take a plural form at all, it's NEZ in any case). Also, while here mostly irrelevant, some words may have multiple terminations depending on context (un aïeul, des aïeux/aïeuls)... And that's just French, so I hope for an API :D

Answer (score 0):

Actually, after careful consideration, it is simpler to iconize this issue, by which I mean, use **graphical elements instead of text**. This way avoids the issue of multiple grammatical rules in languages. If anyone knows of an iPhone API that deals with grammatical localization though, I'm still intellectually interested. Among other things, because though I never would have expected so, the iPhone 4S advertisements showed that *visually-impaired people use the iPhone and icons are not very well suited to them* :D

It also allows me to transform a screen that was getting cluttered and streamline the experience.